# Display Calendar in android application

Tags: android

I have one android application, in which I have to display calendar in one screen. On clicking on a particular date, I have to add or delete my particular items and events. I need some help on this topic please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
AddToCalendar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                Intent calendarIntent = new Intent() ; 
                calendarIntent.setClassName("com.android.calendar","com.android.calendar.AgendaActivity"); 
                startActivity(calendarIntent); 
            } 
        });
```